# How to 1. convert 4,550 dbf files to csv files 2. concatenate files based on names 3. concatenate all csv's into one big data csv for analysis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, cmd

I have multiple `dbf` files (~4,550) in multiple folders and sub-directories (~400) separated by state. 
The data was given to me in `dbf` files on a weekly basis separated by state.

Ex.

```
"Datafiles\DAT_01_APRIL_2019\DAT_01_APRIL_2019\FL\DATA5393.DBF"
"Datafiles\DAT_01_APRIL_2019\DAT_01_APRIL_2019\FL\DATA5414.DBF"
"Datafiles\DAT_01_APRIL_2019\DAT_01_APRIL_2019\NJ\DATA890.DBF"
"Datafiles\DAT_01_APRIL_2019\DAT_01_APRIL_2019\NJ\DATA1071.DBF"

"Datafiles\DAT_01_JUly_2019\DAT_01_JUlY_2019\FL\DATA5393.DBF"
"Datafiles\DAT_01_JUly_2019\DAT_01_JUlY_2019\FL\DATA5414.DBF"
"Datafiles\DAT_01_JUly_2019\DAT_01_JUlY_2019\NJ\DATA890.DBF"
"Datafiles\DAT_01_JUly_2019\DAT_01_JUlY_2019\NJ\DATA1071.DBF"
```

How would I convert + merge all the `dbf` files into one `csv` for each state i.e. keeping the states separate (for regional data analysis)?

Currently using `Python 3` and `Jupyter` notebooks on windows 10.

This problem seems to be solvable using python, I have attempted to experiment with `dbf2csv` and other `dbf` and `csv` functions.

Code below shows some great starting points. Research was done through many posts and my own experimentation. 
I'm still getting started with using python for working with files, but I'm not entirely sure how to code around the tedious tasks.

I typically use the functions below to convert to `csv`, followed by a line in the command promt to combine all `csv` files into one.

The function below converts one specific `dbf` to `csv`

```py
import csv
from dbfread import DBF

def dbf_to_csv(dbf_table_pth):#Input a dbf, output a csv, same name, same path, except extension
    csv_fn = dbf_table_pth[:-4]+ ".csv" #Set the csv file name
    table = DBF(dbf_table_pth)# table variable is a DBF object
    with open(csv_fn, 'w', newline = '') as f:# create a csv file, fill it with dbf content
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(table.field_names)# write the column name
        for record in table:# write the rows
            writer.writerow(list(record.values()))
    return csv_fn# return the csv name
```

The script below converts all dbf files in a given folder to csv format.
This works great, but doesn't take the subfolders and sub-directories into consideration.

```py
import fnmatch
import os
import csv
import time
import datetime
import sys
from dbfread import DBF, FieldParser, InvalidValue          
# pip install dbfread if needed

class MyFieldParser(FieldParser):
    def parse(self, field, data):
        try:
            return FieldParser.parse(self, field, data)
        except ValueError:
            return InvalidValue(data)


debugmode=0         # Set to 1 to catch all the errors.            

for infile in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(infile, '*.dbf'):
        outfile = infile[:-4] + ".csv"
        print("Converting " + infile + " to " + outfile + ". Each period represents 2,000 records.")
        counter = 0
        starttime=time.clock()
        with open(outfile, 'w') as csvfile:
            table = DBF(infile, parserclass=MyFieldParser, ignore_missing_memofile=True)
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            writer.writerow(table.field_names)
            for i, record in enumerate(table):
                for name, value in record.items():
                    if isinstance(value, InvalidValue):
                        if debugmode == 1:
                            print('records[{}][{!r}] == {!r}'.format(i, name, value))
                writer.writerow(list(record.values()))
                counter +=1
                if counter%100000==0:
                    sys.stdout.write('!' + '\r\n')
                    endtime=time.clock()
#                     print (str("{:,}".format(counter))) + " records in " + #str(endtime-starttime) + " seconds."
                elif counter%2000==0:
                    sys.stdout.write('.')
                else:
                    pass
        print("")
        endtime=time.clock()
        print ("Processed " + str("{:,}".format(counter)) + " records in " + str(endtime-starttime) + " seconds (" + str((endtime-starttime)/60) + " minutes.)")
        print (str(counter / (endtime-starttime)) + " records per second.")
        print("")
```

But this process is too tedious considering there are over 400 sub-folders.

Then using the command prompt, I type
`copy *.csv combine.csv` but this can be done with `python` as well.
Currently experimenting with `Os.Walk`, but have not made any major progress.

Ideally, the output should be a csv file with all the combined data for each individual state.

Ex.

```
"\Datafiles\FL.csv"
"\Datafiles\NJ.csv"
```

It would also be alright if the output was into a pandas dataframe for each individual state.

**UPDATE**
Edit: I was able to convert all the dbf files to csv using the os.walk. 
Os.walk has also been helpful to provide me with a list of directories which contain the dbf and csv files. 
Ex.

```py
fl_dirs= ['\Datafiles\\01_APRIL_2019\\01_APRIL_2019\\FL',
 '\Datafiles\\01_JUly_2019\\01_JUlY_2019\\FL',
 '\Datafiles\\03_JUNE_2019\\03_JUNE_2019\\FL',
 '\Datafiles\\04_MARCH_2019\\04_MARCH_2019\\FL']
```

I simply want to access the identical csv files in those directories and combine them into one csv file with python.

UPDATE: SOLVED THIS!I wrote a script that can do everything I needed!

Comment: Why do you want to combine the CSV files with `cmd` rather than Python itself?

Comment: So I have a list of directories for each state (5 lists) containing the csv files of interest along with other files. Each csv file has the same column headers. How would I go about accessing the csv files from an individual list of directories and combine them all into one csv file taking the headings into account?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be simplified using os.walk (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir).

The sub-directories can be traversed and the absolute path of each dbf file can be appended to separate lists based on the state.

Then, the files can be converted to csv using the function dbf_to_csv which then can be combined using concat feature included in pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

**EDIT:** The following code might help. Its not tested though.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# basepath here
base_path="" 
#output dir here
output_path=""


#Create dictionary to store all absolute path
path_dict={"FL":[],"NJ":[]}

#recursively look up into base path
for abs_path,curr_dir,file_list in os.walk(base_path):
    if abs_path.endswith("FL"):
        path_dict["FL"].extend([os.path.join(abs_path,file) for file in file_list])
    elif abs_path.endswith ("NJ"):
        path_dict["NJ"].extend([os.path.join(abs_path,file) for file in file_list])

for paths in path_dict:
    df=pd.concat(
        [pd.read_csv(i) for i in set(path_dict[paths])],
        ignore_index=True
    )
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(output_path,paths+".csv"),index=False)
```